# GTA Money Exploit/Loading Areas

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Towards the end of this money exploit tip video, link bellow, the video talked about how the hack won't work again if you leave the area **after** taking the money (the case won't reload when you come back).

What I'm wondering is if I do the exploit x numbers of times, but on the last time I don't take the case, will the case not be there after I leave the site and come back later?

Comment: To note: At least according to the patch notes I had read, this glitch is fixed.

Comment: @Aeo yes it's patched : http://www.gamezone.com/news/2013/10/04/gta-5-title-update-allegedly-fixes-infinite-money-exploit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works.  I was able to do this trick many times with Franklin, then leave the case there.  I came back (real) days later with Trevor and performed the trick again.